# When are Brauer tree algebras Hopf algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

> Question 1: Which Brauer tree algebras are Hopf algebras?

For example every representation-finite group algebra is a Brauer tree algebra and thus a Hopf algebra, but not every Brauer tree algebra appears as a block of a group algebra.

> Question 2: Let $Q$ be a quiver of Dynkin type and A the trivial extension of $KQ$. When is $A$ a Hopf algebra? For example for linear oriented Dynkin type $A_n$ we get a Hopf algebra. I am not sure wether it depends on the orientation.

Note that the questions can be combined (up to omitting one infinite family of algebras called penny-farthing algebras), to ask what are the representation-finite symmetric Frobenius algebas over an algebraically closed field that are Hopf algebras?

> Question 3: When is the preprojective algebra corresponding to a Dynkin type Q a Hopf algebra?

Comment: A block of a group algebra is not necessarily a Hopf algebra.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks, I changed that.

Comment: Having a Hopf algebra structure is not a Morita invariant property, so are you interested in whether a basic algebra has a Hopf algebra structure, or just some algebra in the same Morita class? Also, as the group algebra case illustrates, the question doesn't reduce to connected algebras. It might be that a representation-finite symmetric Frobenius algebra does not have a Hopf algebra structure, but is a direct factor of a representation-finite symmetric Frobenius algebra that does.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, but I hope for a rather positive answer like that most of them are Hopf algebras. (But I have no expierence on this question)